# PowerMock and EasyMock

Tags: junit, easymock, powermock

Is there a good reference material or links where one can find good resource for jUnit, PowerMock and EasyMock.

Though good amount of information is available on the net , but is there a single point of access to all that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single site that contains all of the information about all of the testing tools. A good place to start with all three would be the following:

[Mockito API Documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html)
[JUnit Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started)

[EasyMock API Documentation](http://www.easymock.org/EasyMock3_1_Documentation.html)

There are also plenty of good examples and tutorials out there on the web, but the official documentation is usually a good place to start.